# program exits when shellexcute was called

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, windows-7

win7 OS, vs2008.
My program disappears when shellexcute was called,

It's a WTL project and the code like these:

*.h

```
COMMAND_HANDLER(IDC_BTN_LOGIN, BN_CLICKED, DoLogin)
```

*.cpp

```
LRESULT XLoginView::DoLogin(WORD, WORD, HWND, BOOL&)
{
    ::ShellExecute(NULL, _T("open"), _T("http://mysite.com/login.php"), NULL,NULL, SW_SHOW);
    return 0;
}
```

when the login button was clicked, then my program was disappeard and the visual studio exit too.

Even the code is such simple as these:

```
int _tmain(int argc, TCHAR* argv[], TCHAR* envp[])
{
    int nRetCode = 0;

    // initialize MFC and print and error on failure
    if (!AfxWinInit(::GetModuleHandle(NULL), NULL, ::GetCommandLine(), 0))
    {
        // TODO: change error code to suit your needs
        _tprintf(_T("Fatal Error: MFC initialization failed\n"));
        nRetCode = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        // TODO: code your application's behavior here.

       ShellExecute(NULL, L"open", L"http://stackoverflow.com", NULL, NULL, SW_SHOW);
    }

    return nRetCode;
}
```

The site (http://stackoverflow.com) was openned only the first running or debugging, then the second time and over, the visual studio disappears at the same time.

Here is a same problem, but didn't give the reason
http://bbs.pediy.com/showthread.php?t=130968

---

update 2013-08-27

As IInspectable's suggestion, it works ok with local resource, but web resource.

Google Chrome is my default browser, so I trust some other browsers as default browser, then get these result below:

(1) Default browser: Google Chrome

If I directly run my program, it is ok, it works. The web resource(URL) was openned, the program doesn't crush.

But if I debug the program from visual studio's button "start debugging", not only the program exit but also visual studio exit when the button who's event code calls "ShellExcute".

(2) Default browser: Firfox or Internet Explorer

The program works, it doesn't crush or disappear whenever I run it directly or debug it from visual studio.

---

As the above I think maybe it's because the program's Privilege is not enough.
so I trust the code below, then the problem disappeared.

```
void UpPrivilege()
{
    HANDLE hToken;
    TOKEN_PRIVILEGES tkp;

    OpenProcessToken (GetCurrentProcess (), TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES | TOKEN_QUERY, &hToken);

    LookupPrivilegeValue(NULL, L"SeDebugPrivileges", &tkp.Privileges[0].Luid);

    tkp.PrivilegeCount = 1;
    tkp.Privileges[0].Attributes = SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED;

    AdjustTokenPrivileges(hToken, FALSE, &tkp, 0, NULL, 0);
}
```

Comment: `ShellExecute` doesn't wait for the launched process to finish. [See here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/c924bc92-1cde-46ba-a3ab-e097208e5b60/waiting-for-a-program-to-finish-using-shellexecuteex-in-c) for a solution using `ShellExecuteEx`.

Comment: actually, Shellexcute was called at some button-event, the program was disappeard when the button was clicked, while the the visual studio was disappeard too. such as the code in the question also cause the problem at my computer

Comment: What dou you mean by "some button-event" ? There is no event whatsoever in your code. Please tell us exactly what you are doing, in other word, what disappears when you click on wich button.

Comment: -1 What you state in the comments contradicts what is stated in the question. You are wasting our time.

Comment: I trust to use ShellExecuteEx, Winexec, but the same problem still appear.

Comment: Does `ShellExecuteEx` succeed if you pass it a local resource (like C:\test.txt)? If it does, but still crashes with a web resource I would assume your system is infected by a virus.

Answer (score 0):

update 2013-08-27

As IInspectable's suggestion, it works ok with local resource, but web resource.

Google Chrome is my default browser, so I trust some other browsers as default browser, then get these result below:

(1) Default browser: Google Chrome

If I directly run my program, it is ok, it works. The web resource(URL) was openned, the program doesn't crush.

But if I debug the program from visual studio's button "start debugging", not only the program exit but also visual studio exit when the button who's event code calls "ShellExcute".

(2) Default browser: Firfox or Internet Explorer

The program works, it doesn't crush or disappear whenever I run it directly or debug it from visual studio.

---

As the above I think maybe it's because the program's Privilege is not enough.
so I trust the code below, then the problem disappeared.

```
void UpPrivilege()
{
    HANDLE hToken;
    TOKEN_PRIVILEGES tkp;

    OpenProcessToken (GetCurrentProcess (), TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES | TOKEN_QUERY, &hToken);

    LookupPrivilegeValue(NULL, L"SeDebugPrivileges", &tkp.Privileges[0].Luid);

    tkp.PrivilegeCount = 1;
    tkp.Privileges[0].Attributes = SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED;

    AdjustTokenPrivileges(hToken, FALSE, &tkp, 0, NULL, 0);
}
```